# C++ API Returns different value when called by C# Wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, interop, precision, dllimport

I'm doing a migration project which involves a C++ code being called in C# via `DllImport`. But its return value differs depending on who's calling the code.

Below is the sample code:

```
int WINAPI foo()
{   
    double size = (double)max * step * 1000.0 * rate;
    return (int) size;
}
```

I tried debugging it using Visual Studio's native debugger and it returns, for example, 512.

But when I run it in the C++ Base Code, it returns 511.

Is there some difference between C++ and C# when handling floating points? considering this is the same C++ code, only being called by two different languages.

Comment: It's the same C++ code but is it being compiled in the same way in both cases? There are certainly compiler options that can affect the way floating point operations work.

Comment: Is one running the debug version and the other the release version?  The debug version simulates the FPU while the release uses the microprocessor FPU.  So sometimes you get different results.  Some micro's have bugs in the FPU and give answers that differ (usually very tiny).

Comment: The debug version does not simulate FPU @jdweng, I honestly have no idea where that came from

Comment: @Rhen The issue will be the floating point control word. Use some diagnostics to see how that differs between the two host executables. Use _control_fp in your DLL to compare.

Comment: Hi, my advise would be return the value as double and check whether return value is same or different. If same round it as per your requirement.

Comment: @john i'll look into this. the DLL where this function belongs was migrated from VS2010 to VS2012 and some DLL properties might have been modified.

Comment: @Abhijit i dont think this is a problem in the casting. the value of size is 256.00000 even before being casted to int.